# Last column append python

Tags: python

I have the following code and when i try to append my `B` it doesn't append as expecting.

```
B=[]
E = np.zeros(3)
for i in [1, 10, 30, 50]:
    for j in range(3):
        E1 = 0
        for k in range(5):
            Ene=k+rand()
            E1 = E1 + Ene
        E[j] = E1
    B.append(E)
```

I get the following results :

```
 [array([12.35627688, 12.16296235, 11.75953804]),
 array([12.35627688, 12.16296235, 11.75953804]),
 array([12.35627688, 12.16296235, 11.75953804]),
 array([12.35627688, 12.16296235, 11.75953804])]
```

which is four times the last value of `E`.
But when i move the `E = np.zeros(3)` just after the first `for` loop, i get the results i want which are differents values on each component of B.

I don't understand why i get the last value of E four times in B when `E = np.zeros(3)` is before the for loop. Can anyone help me ? 
Thanks!

Comment: The line `E[j] = E1` modifies `E` in-place, so you end up appending the same array multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you added a reference and not a copy of E to the list and so changing E also changes the content of B. Check https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html to add a copy. To be on the safe side use deepcopy.

```
import numpy as np
from random import random as rand
from copy import deepcopy

B = []
E = np.zeros(3)
for i in [1, 10, 30, 50]:
    for j in range(3):
        E1 = 0
        for k in range(5):
            Ene=k+rand()
            E1 = E1 + Ene
        E[j] = E1
    B.append(deepcopy(E))

print(B)
```

xxx@yyy:~/Desktop/test$ python3 test.py
[array([13.16046629, 13.07833955, 11.39445043]), array([11.70113908, 11.59176892, 12.9708855 ]), array
([12.85908412, 12.8424841 , 12.62336043]), array([12.23842107, 13.02196394, 12.54768361])]

Answer (score 1):

When `E = np.zeros(3)` is before the loop, you are only creating one array, and appending it 4 times to the list.
When you change the value, you are changing the same array, and when you look at `B`, you have the same array 4 times, as it is the same object.

When you put `E = np.zeros(3)` inside the `for` , you are creating a new array each time, thus you append different arrays, and when you change the value of one, they do not alter the other.

You can change the last line to `B.append(np.copy(E))` and create copies of `E`, thus appending different arrays to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there are four references to the same array appended to B, you are always updating a single unit of memory thus all the four references end up with the same value.

For efficiency I recommend simply instanciating the full matrix instead of using append and adding rows individually.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the reference to `E` variable hence your result is same array for all entries. Another way to resolve this without needing to copy the emtpy `E` array would be to define a function that outputs the random array you want to append to `B`.

So you can use below code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand as rand

def randomArray():
    E = np.zeros(3)
    for j in range(3):
        E1 = 0
        for k in range(5):
            Ene=k+rand()
            E1 = E1 + Ene
        E[j] = E1
    return E

B=[]
for i in [1, 10, 30, 50]:
    B.append(randomArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Rand() function is not adding values Try with Something like this

```
import numpy as np
import random
B=[]
E = np.zeros(3)
for i in [1, 10, 30, 50]:
    for j in range(3):
        E1 = 0
        for k in range(5):
            Ene=k+random.random()
            E1 = E1 + Ene
        E[j] = E1
    B.append(E)
    print(E)
```